# django unicode to string

Tags: python, django

I stored ip in sqlite database as normal string, but when i try to get that ip from database

```
>>> p = Info.objects.get(id = 1)
>>> p.ip
>>> u"[u'10.10.10.1']"`
```

How I can get normal string "10.10.10.1"

Comment: Could you show us the model field, and how you store data into it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there is a `list` with just one element.

To get the element from the list you could use `p.ip[0]`.

That would give you a `unicode` object, then if you want to convert it to a string (just some bytes) you should use [`encode`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode), i.e. `p.ip[0].encode('utf8')`

Comment: I have same issue. Can we convert it in template?

Answer (score 4):

> I stored ip in sqlite database as normal string

I think you probably stored it incorrectly.

It looks like you did something like this:

```
ips = [u'10.10.10.1']
ip = str(ips)  # gives "[u'10.10.10.1']"
```

But you perhaps you should have done this instead:

```
ip = ips[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`smart_bytes()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/unicode/#useful-utility-functions) to convert unicode to string